# Dig screw object inside a cylinder (Blender 2.8)

Tags: modeling, screw-modifier

I would like to "substract" a screw from a cylinder, as shown on the screenshot below:

[image: Cylinder and screw]

I tried using the Boolean modifier but with no result. (Note: I am a beginner and I may have missused the Boolean modifier).

What I would like is to end with a nut.

Please apologize if my english is bad (not my native language).